# how to connect telegram bot with google sheet?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

However, such functionality is often redundant for simple tasks, which makes the work not very convenient. This is especially true for mobile devices. So it would be cool to make it possible to work with tables through other interfaces.

i need to connect telegram bot with google sheet with this condition:
all users get his note from telegram bot, if enter his password correct, i need a javascript code to do that with google sheet.

[image: example]